# Generate selected rows script SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

In Sql Server ,
I don't want to generate whole table data script.I want the script of my own inserted 100 rows script . My table have huge record and it takes long if i  generate script of whole table Also its not good to  find my rows again from that script and pick.
Is there any way to put criteria where i can specify my range ?
something like where condition  as we use in sql queries ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show your table definitions for both source and destination

Comment: Dear Kamran,
As we developer regularly generate script by right click on database and go to Generate script and select objects and generate.

i want to do same but just need criteria place where i can put my condition and generate script of my own range.

Comment: if you are generating the insert statements using a select statement then I cant see why you should not be able to specify your range in the where clause but without knowing exactly what your schema looks like I cannot be more help. Also if you are moving data about you really should look into using SSIS as it is made for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [this](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt).

It's called sp_generate_inserts. There are many examples in the header of the stored procedure. Take a look at example number 4.